# Weka decision tree node count too high

Tags: weka

I am trying to interpret the string representation of a Weka RandomTree. Training set has 1000 records (instances). Looking at the string the number of instances in the leafs seems to add up to 1030. How is this possible? Am I misinterpreting the string somehow?

See the complete run description below.

Note the following:

`Total Number of Instances             1000`

while collecting all the counts from the leafs:
`(10/0),(1/0),(354/0),(18/1),(37/0),(11/0),(9/4),(5/0),(7/3),(5/0),(20/0),(1/0),(2/0),(168/0),(1/0),(145/0),(61/3),(3/1),(5/0),(44/13),(8/0),(10/2),(63/0),(8/3),(4/0)`

leads to a total of 1030.

Thanks!

Here is the complete run description:

```
=== Run information ===

Scheme:       weka.classifiers.trees.RandomTree -K 0 -M 1.0 -V 0.001 -S 1 -depth 5
Relation:     test-data
Instances:    1000
Attributes:   5
              feature1
              feature2
              feature3
              feature4
              class
Test mode:    evaluate on training data

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===


RandomTree
==========

feature2 < -0.27
|   feature2 < -0.61
|   |   feature3 < 1.09
|   |   |   feature2 < -2.41
|   |   |   |   feature2 < -2.45 : 0 (10/0)
|   |   |   |   feature2 >= -2.45 : 1 (1/0)
|   |   |   feature2 >= -2.41
|   |   |   |   feature2 < -0.7 : 0 (354/0)
|   |   |   |   feature2 >= -0.7 : 0 (18/1)
|   |   feature3 >= 1.09
|   |   |   feature2 < -0.94 : 0 (37/0)
|   |   |   feature2 >= -0.94
|   |   |   |   feature1 < -0.02 : 0 (11/0)
|   |   |   |   feature1 >= -0.02 : 0 (9/4)
|   feature2 >= -0.61
|   |   feature3 < -0.34
|   |   |   feature1 < 1.19 : 1 (5/0)
|   |   |   feature1 >= 1.19
|   |   |   |   feature2 < -0.39 : 0 (7/3)
|   |   |   |   feature2 >= -0.39 : 0 (5/0)
|   |   feature3 >= -0.34
|   |   |   feature2 < -0.32 : 0 (20/0)
|   |   |   feature2 >= -0.32
|   |   |   |   feature2 < -0.3 : 1 (1/0)
|   |   |   |   feature2 >= -0.3 : 0 (2/0)
feature2 >= -0.27
|   feature1 < 1.19
|   |   feature3 < -0.11 : 1 (168/0)
|   |   feature3 >= -0.11
|   |   |   feature3 < -0.1 : 0 (1/0)
|   |   |   feature3 >= -0.1
|   |   |   |   feature4 < 0.59 : 1 (145/0)
|   |   |   |   feature4 >= 0.59 : 1 (61/3)
|   feature1 >= 1.19
|   |   feature2 < 0.82
|   |   |   feature2 < -0.18
|   |   |   |   feature2 < -0.21 : 0 (3/1)
|   |   |   |   feature2 >= -0.21 : 0 (5/0)
|   |   |   feature2 >= -0.18
|   |   |   |   feature1 < 2.28 : 1 (44/13)
|   |   |   |   feature1 >= 2.28 : 0 (8/0)
|   |   feature2 >= 0.82
|   |   |   feature1 < 2.67
|   |   |   |   feature1 < 1.33 : 1 (10/2)
|   |   |   |   feature1 >= 1.33 : 1 (63/0)
|   |   |   feature1 >= 2.67
|   |   |   |   feature1 < 2.97 : 0 (8/3)
|   |   |   |   feature1 >= 2.97 : 1 (4/0)

Size of the tree : 49
Max depth of tree: 5

Time taken to build model: 0.05 seconds

=== Evaluation on training set ===

Time taken to test model on training data: 0.03 seconds

=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         970               97      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        30                3      %
Kappa statistic                          0.94  
Mean absolute error                      0.0421
Root mean squared error                  0.145 
Relative absolute error                  8.4142 %
Root relative squared error             29.0073 %
Total Number of Instances             1000     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

                 TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
                 0.964    0.024    0.976      0.964    0.970      0.940    0.997     0.996     0
                 0.976    0.036    0.964      0.976    0.970      0.940    0.997     0.995     1
Weighted Avg.    0.970    0.030    0.970      0.970    0.970      0.940    0.997     0.996     

=== Confusion Matrix ===

   a   b   <-- classified as
 486  18 |   a = 0
  12 484 |   b = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting  what the numbers in parentheses mean. I think that you are interpreting this as `(Correct instances / Incorrect instances)` at the node, but actually it means `(Total instances / Incorrect instances)`.

At each leaf node, there is a pair of numbers in parentheses, e.g. the seventh leaf says:

```
feature1 >= -0.02 : 0 (9/4)
```

This means that 9 of the original instances got to this leaf. The 4 means that *of the 9 instances that got to this leaf*, 4 were incorrectly classified.  If you sum all of the first numbers in the parenthesized pairs,  they total 1000. The sum of the second numbers is 30. That matches the number of errors given later in your output:

```
Correctly Classified Instances         970               97      %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        30                3      %
```

Note that the number of errors will only agree when you use

```
=== Evaluation on training set ===
```

as you did. The numbers will be different under cross-validation.

Comment: Thanks! also got this answer here:
https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/message/AT4SBJMO6D2X3THQHZFT2OHAA6E4CMKZ/